# Why do php variables not work if inserted in a function, in a Linux pc?

Tags: php, json, linux, object, ubuntu

On PC Linux the php code does not correctly insert the indicated variables.
The same code on Windows PC works correctly.

Both PCs have PHP version 7.3, I tried to install different versions but it continues to fail.

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database_locale.php';
include_once '../objects/locale.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$ipServerWebSocket = $data->ipServerWebSocket;
```

If I execute a print_f() of the variable $ipServerWebSocket the value is correct, but if I insert it in the part of code below it has as value "empty" and php returns the error:

> [Thu Oct 10 18:32:56.509354 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 8133] [client
>   10.99.99.126:44054] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'idEliminaCoda' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/factotumSidRomagna/api/locale/stampaEliminaCode.php on
>   line 26, referer: http://10.99.99.25/factotumSidRomagna/ [Thu Oct 10
>   18:32:56.509407 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 8133] [client
>   10.99.99.126:44054] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'cEliminaCoda' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/factotumSidRomagna/api/locale/stampaEliminaCode.php on
>   line 27, referer: http://10.99.99.25/factotumSidRomagna/ [Thu Oct 10
>   18:32:56.509423 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 8133] [client
>   10.99.99.126:44054] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'dEliminaCoda' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/factotumSidRomagna/api/locale/stampaEliminaCode.php on
>   line 28, referer: http://10.99.99.25/factotumSidRomagna/ [Thu Oct 10
>   18:32:56.509465 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 8133] [client
>   10.99.99.126:44054] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'valoreCliente' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/factotumSidRomagna/api/locale/stampaEliminaCode.php on
>   line 29, referer: http://10.99.99.25/factotumSidRomagna/ [Thu Oct 10
>   18:32:56.509481 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 8133] [client
>   10.99.99.126:44054] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'nomeImmagine' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/factotumSidRomagna/api/locale/stampaEliminaCode.php on
>   line 30, referer: http://10.99.99.25/factotumSidRomagna/ [Thu Oct 10
>   18:32:56.540199 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 8133] [client
>   10.99.99.126:44054] PHP Warning:  fopen(../../app/assets/img/eliminaCode/_.png): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/factotumSidRomagna/app/assets/php/fpdf.php on line 1259,
>   referer: http://10.99.99.25/factotumSidRomagna/

Code:

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database_locale.php';
include_once '../objects/locale.php';

// get id of product to be edited
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set product property values
$ipServerWebSocket = $data->ipServerWebSocket;

// get database connection
$database = new DatabaseLocale();
$db = $database->getConnection($ipServerWebSocket);

// prepare product object
$locale = new Locale($db);

$locale->ideliminacoda = $data->idEliminaCoda;
$locale->codice = $data->cEliminaCoda;
$locale->descrizione = $data->dEliminaCoda;
$locale->valorecliente = $data->valoreCliente;
$locale->nomeImmagine = $data->nomeImmagine;

// update the product
if($locale->stampa()){ ....}
```

PHP FILE OBJECT LOCALE:

```
function stampa(){

        //define('__ROOT__', str_replace('\\', '/' , dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))));
        define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));

        require_once (__ROOT__.'/app/assets/php/fpdf.php'); 
        $printerFolder = __ROOT__ . "/app/assets/printer/";

        // sanitize
        $this->ideliminacoda=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->ideliminacoda));
        $this->codice=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->codice));
        $this->descrizione=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->descrizione));
        $this->valorecliente=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->valorecliente + 1));
        $this->nomeImmagine=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->nomeImmagine));

        $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(79,79));
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Image('../../app/assets/img/eliminaCode/'.$this->codice.'_'.$this->descrizione.'.png',34,0,10,0);
```

All this on Windows PC works properly without giving errors, Why?

Comment: Because errors are not enabled on Windows PC?

Comment: Errors is enabled on Windows PC! php.ini of Windows PC:

display_errors=On
display_startup_errors=On
log_errors=On

Comment: Are you posting to this script? Using a form? AJAX?

Comment: i use Angular, this is the code for start the request:

factory.stampaLocaleAvanzaNumero = function(idEliminaCoda, ...){
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                'idEliminaCoda' : idEliminaCoda,
                'cEliminaCoda' : cEliminaCoda,
                'dEliminaCoda' : dEliminaCoda,
...
                'ipServerWebSocket' : ipServerWebSocket
            },
            url: 'http://' + ipServerWebSocket + '/factotumSidRomagna/api/locale/stampaEliminaCode.php'
        });
    };